General support
I am looking for a general support contact for civi - can any one help or direct me to someone?
I have been unable to access my account for 2 weeks and as an organisation we can't work out why.
Thanks so much!!

Have a look here: https://civicrm.org/civicrm/experts and find an organization near you?

Are you using Spark?  If so, contact spark@civicrm.org or use the spark channel on https://chat.civicrm.org/

Even if you are not using Spark you can ask for help both in the Chat channel that Aiden has linked to, or in StackExchange.
